# Copy Specific column from csv file to another file with specific word location using powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, azure-powershell

I am new to PowerShell its just been a day that I started using this, I need some help regarding building script for my model. These are the steps

1. I am taking file content and I have taken everything in different variable like:
   $Test_Name, $Test_number, $Result and consequently imported the data from CSV into these variables:

```
Import-Csv .\result.csv | ForEach-Object {($Test_Result += $_."Test Result"),($Test_number +=$_."Test Number")
```

.... and so on

2. Now I have data into some powershell variables and now I want these variable content to be pasted to another file named output.txt/docs upon several specific parameters like %%PasteHereTestName%%, %%PasteHereTestNumber%%.

Can anyone guide me on this, I have tried several ways but it seems like I need some guidance.

**this will be used by Azure devops pipeline to copy the content from test file to output doc file..

Comment: You said you "tried several ways" without providing a code snippet. Please summarize your issue in a straightforward manner, explain what you want to do and what you tried with some example code.

And please have a look at the [How to ask guideline](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Import the CSV into a variable and you can address each attribute directly, and write individual columns/attributes to a new CSV file by including the select-object statement

```
$Results = Import-csv c:\temp\testfile.csv
$results | select-object Column1, Column2, Column3 | export-csv C:\temp\proddata.csv
```